# iterate through folder and sub folders to find a specific file

Tags: python

I want to loop through a folder then its sub folder find a .wav file and rename it.  I am using this code below but it will find all the files and print it . Here the folder final_Earthquake and many sub folders. I want to work one by one giving a specific tag to the files in a certain sub folders. With this code below I can't find which sub folder is the .wav file coming from.

I want to first find the files in sub folder work with them and then go to another sub folder and so on.

```
 import os

rootdir = r'C:\Users\KUSHAL\Desktop\Final_Earthquake'

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for dire in dirs:
        for file in files:
         filepath = subdir+os.sep +file
         if filepath.endswith('.wav'):
          #do my stuff 

          print (dire + file)
```

Comment: print `filepath` instead of `file`???

Comment: So the `subdir` is actually the full path to the directory. Also if you're looking at file extensions it should be fine and quicker to look at `file.endswith('.wav')` instead of building a filepath. If you do need the filepath, people seem to prefer if you use os.path.join as in `filepath = os.path.join(subdir, file)`

Oh and the reason you're not getting the subfolder is because you're printing `file`. Try printing `subdir` instead

Comment: @CharlieG I have update my code is my approach correct ?

Comment: No. [Look at the `os.path` examples](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/os_walk.htm) more closely